# After a fresh install of Android Studio I got an error on Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I've just format my PC and I've installed Android Studio 0.8.4 with all APIs in the SDK. My problem is when I try to run a new project, I get this message:

```
Gradle 'myproject' project refresh failed
Error:org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildDirectory()Ljava/io/File;
```

Anyone knows where is the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?

Comment: The default gradle wrapper that comes with Android Studio, I don't know how to see the version.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it helps, but i figured that in my "**External Library**" is showing just my **JDK** and **< Android API 19 >** not the L API. Looks like that this **GradleProject.getBuildDirectory()** is looking for the **java.io.File** dependency from L API and is not finding it. Maybe the lack of external reference to L API is part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was:

1. **Uninstall Android Studio** (delete folders, on users location, like .android, .gradle, etc.)
2. **Download the package with installer** on https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html
3. **Version 0.8.0** -> The latest version that I was using was 0.8.4, this isn't a installer version is a zip
4. **Install** this version.
5. **The problem disappear, *including after an update petition of Android Studio to version 0.8.2.***
6. I guess then it would be some kind of bug in version 0.8.4.

I hope this works for someone else. Bye.